# How find nth largest and smallest number in Pig and Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I have table with column id, name, and salary
I want to find Nth number of largest and smallest salary from table

```
Id Name Salary
--------------
1  aa   11111
--------------
2  bb   77777
-------------
3 cc 33333
-------------
4 dd 44444
-------------
5 ee 99999
```

Comment: Both Pig and Hive support ranking functions.

Answer (score 1):

In Hive:

*For nth MAX salary*

**Query:**

```
select id,name,salary from (
select id,name,salary,rank() over(ORDER BY salary DESC)ran from salarytable ) s 
where ran=1;
```

**Output:**

```
5 ee 99999
```

*For nth MIN salary*

**Query:**

```
select id,name,salary from (
select id,name,salary,rank() over(ORDER BY salary ASC)ran from salarytable ) s 
where ran=4;
```

**Output:**

```
4 dd 4444
```

P.S: The `rank()`'s number would define the nth value here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use LIMIT or Rank.Using LIMIT, load the data,sort it by descending order for getting the largest salaries in order.Limit the data to Nth record.This will give you N records where Nth record will be at the bottom of the dataset. Sort it again in ascending order which will give you the Nth record as the top record and then use LIMIT again to get the top record.Use similar steps for smallest.Where you sort by ascending order,limit to Nth record and sort again by descending order and limit 1.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (id:int,name:chararray,salary:int);
B = ORDER A BY Salary DESC;
C = LIMIT B 4; --Note: N = 4
D = ORDER C BY salary ASC;
E = LIMIT D 1;
```